# How to Handle "zip code" window popup without iframe in Amazon using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver, zipcode

I almost try every code which is related to popup windows using programing language is python coding and selenium but none of them is working `send.key("XXXXX")` command in zip code. Because mostly they are related to `iframe` in page source so either it handle with window `switch_to.frame()` or `switch_to.window`. In my case there is no `iframe` in page source and the popup windows doesn't send keys in that input zip code. So i need help for handle those kinds of windows popup python and selenium programing to handles popup window.

```
driver.switch_to.frame()
driver.switch_to.window()
driver.switch_to.alert()
```

```
browser.get('www.amazon.com')
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="nav-global-location-popover-link"]""").click()
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(1000)
    browser.switch_to.active_element()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GLUXZipUpdateInput"]').send_keys("85224")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on delivery location bar and set the pin code programmatically, Like below

```html
loc = str(driver.find_element_by_id("glow-ingress-line2").text).strip().replace(" ", "")
        if loc == "India" in driver.page_source:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "nav-packard-glow-loc-icon")))
            driver.find_element_by_id("nav-packard-glow-loc-icon").click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "GLUXZipUpdateInput")))
            driver.find_element_by_id("GLUXZipUpdateInput").send_keys(10001)

            ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ENTER).perform()

            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "GLUXConfirmClose")))
            driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.